# Matplotlib blank plot (supposed to have subplots)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use Matplotlib to generate plot axes within a function called within a for-loop and use these axes to create a final multi-panel figure. However, despite the axes showing the proper lines when they are being created within my function, the multi-panel figure ends up with empty axes. What am I doing wrong? My code is below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_axis(alpha, beta):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 4))
    x = np.arange(10, dtype=float)
    y = alpha + x * beta

    ax.plot(x, y)

    return ax

def create_plot():
    alpha = 3.

    axes_pool = []
    for i in range(4):
        axes_pool.append(create_axis(alpha, i))

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 4)

    for i in range(len(axes)):
        axes[i] = axes_pool[i]

    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_plot()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the axes to the subfunction to allow the plt on the already created subplots.

Right approach is sending the axes as one of the parameters for `create_axis` function,which will plot the required data in the supplied axis.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_axis(ax,alpha, beta):
    x = np.arange(10, dtype=float)
    y = alpha + x * beta

    ax.plot(x, y)


def create_plot():
    alpha = 3.

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 4,figsize=(5,4)))

    for i,ax in enumerate(axes):
        create_axis(ax,alpha,i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_plot()
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Would have been helpful if you added some text to your answer. You just posted a code without explaining what the problem was and what you did

Comment: Added the explanation. Thanks